# warning:array elements are more than 100

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code declaring an array.

```
#define MAX_ELEMENT 150
Struct_arr  arr_elem[MAX_ELEMENT];
```

Here `Struct_arr` is a structure. On compilation i am getting the warning for this later line as:

```
warning:array elements are more than 100
```

could someone please help me about this?

regards,
vivG

Comment: Guhq, do you use compiler for embedded systems?

Answer (score 4):

That's almost certainly the result of a `#warning` directive in the code somewhere. C++ itself does not limit you to 99 array elements, this will be an artificial limit introduced for some reason.

My advice would be to search for that message and see if there's any comments close by which explain *why* that's a problem. Something like:

```
fgrep 'array has more than' *.c *.cpp *.h *.hpp
```

in as UNIX-like operating system would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks much for help. I found the problem going by your description.

Comment: @Bibaswan: Please click the checkmark at the top left corner of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings says that you're trying to allocate a big array on the stack. On typical linux system, the stack has 8Mb, so it can be quite easy to reach that limit (causing a segfault). This is why you have this warning.

As you tagged your question as C++, please notice that it's not very common to use C-style array in C++. You would rather use an

```
std::vector<Struct_arr> arr_elem(150);
```

This allocates a vector of 150 elements, but it can be dynamicaly resized, so if you allocated such a big array "just in case", then a std::vector is even more the way to go.

Last thing, just use plain old constants instead of macros, there is really no benefit from using them in this particular situation.